# How can I update nginx to lastest stable version?

Tags: linux, nginx, update

I'm using a CentOS 6.6 Linux server and I have nginx 1.7.3 Installed on it . How Can I update Nginx to latest stable version (Nginx 1.8) ?

Comment: Is there a feature in 1.8 that you need? If not, you should stick with 1.7.3 until a newer version is available in the official CentOS repos.

Comment: since the connections to my server are high , the change-log is enticing me to update because it says it can handle more connections . what do u suggest?

Comment: Don't worry about upgrading until you are *sure* that you need it. The benefits of sticking with the official repos are quite high.

Comment: thank u dear EEAA , I will do as you said . I stick with official repo

Answer (score 7):

you can setup the nginx repository for CentOS as described here:
http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#stable
or simply run

```
yum install http://nginx.org/packages/centos/6/noarch/RPMS/nginx-release-centos-6-0.el6.ngx.noarch.rpm
```

once installed the repo run:

```
yum install nginx
```

It should upgrade to the latest stable version

Comment: Would this retain any changes made to the existing Nginx configuration?